# error: no type named 'InterfaceProvider' in namespace 'content::shell'; did you mean '::shell::InterfaceProvider'?

Tags: c++, blink

I am getting the following compile time error when i am including the render_tree_node.h 
in my example.cc

> included from ../../content/shell/browser/my_example.cc:17:
>   In file included from ../../content/browser/frame_host/frame_tree_node.h:17:
>   In file included from 
>   ../../content/browser/renderer_host/render_process_host_impl.h:165:3: error: no type named 'InterfaceProvider' in namespace 'content::shell'; did you mean '::shell::InterfaceProvider' ?

when I compile this withuot adding my_example, it does compile the code.

I have tried adding the Dependency in my BUIDL.gn of my_example.

can anyone help ?

render_process_host_impl.h  looks like this :->

```
   namespace shell {
   class InterfaceRegistry;
   }
   namespace content {
   virtual shell::InterfaceRegistry* GetInterfaceRegistry() = 0;
   }
```

mmExample.cc
 #include "/render_tree_node.h"

> my Question is when i compile myExample.cc the error mentioned above appears else it does not, there are other files are also there which are using this file and this file is compiling i have rechecked even without adding my files also.

what could be the problem ??

Comment: Wait, what? Pure virtual functions in a *namespace*? How would that ever work?

Comment: ????? I am getting error for class **shell::InterfaceRegistry** not for virtual function friend, read the error in description dude.

Comment: Yes, but that's not your *only* error.

Comment: The Error is got fixed by including the render_tree_node.h into the myexample.h, no extra change is required. though I am not getting your point about virtual function, where I am using this virtual function I am using it inside the same namespace, else it will not be visible only.    Anyways thank you so much for helping.

Comment: Virtual functions can only be used within a *class*. Please take some time to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is imperative that we see the *actual* code that causes the errors. And if you retype code into the question, instead of copy-pasting the actual code, then you might add other errors that distracts from the ones you have. Or worse, you might inadvertently *fix* the error in your re-type. Also please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).